# paperclip + S3 => part of url is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

Working on a API allowing to upload pictures with paperclip. everything is working (pictures can be saved on S3) but I can't display the right url's picture in my JSON.

**Model :**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :picture,
    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    default_url: ":s3_eu_url"

    ...  some validations and accessors

end
```

**Serializer :**

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :picture
end
```

**Production.rb :**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  :url => ':s3_domain_url',
  :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  :path => ':class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
  }
}
```

**Paperclip initializer :**

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) do |att, style|
    "#{att.s3_protocol}://#{att.bucket_name}.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{att.path(style)}"
  end
end
```

Running curl to do a post, I got that (the correct url which is working):

```
"http://wetal-assets-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/categories/pictures/000/000/397/original/elec.jpeg?1455186040"
```

url displayed in my JSON :

```
"http://wetal-assets-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

the picture's path is missing and I can't find a way to display it.
Even when I create a method to redefine ":picture" in the serializer in order to return "object.picture.url"...still the same result.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If call `category.image.url` in rails console the url is correct?

Comment: it's incorrect...But I don't understand why and how curl returns a correct one which is works when I try to reach it in my browser.